# LINQ, iterators, selecting and projection

Tags: c#, linq

What I would like to do is use the elegance of LINQ while maintaining an iterator....

essentially

```
Class A
{
  int Position;
  string Name;
}
```

if I have a list of strings, i want to project them into `List<A>` but have the Position be populated in the projection...

```
List<string> names; //filled with strings
```

something like

```
List<A> foo = (from s in names select s).ToList();
```

but have it also iterate over and populate Position..

is this possible?

```
{{Position:0,Name: "name1"},{Position:1, Name: "name2"}, {Position:2, Name: "name3"}....}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    var listOfStrings = new List<string> {"name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"};
    var foo = listOfStrings.Select((value, position) => new {position, value}).ToList();
```

Position will be incremented as a 0-starting index, check the [Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) overload.